# How to show Calendar module on front end in pyrocms

Tags: php, calendar, pyrocms

I just downloaded and installed a calendar module from http://www.cecilieo.com/techblog/free-add-ons-for-pyrocms/.

Has anyone used this plugin before? If yes, please could you please show me how I can make the calendar show up on my website?

Currently, it only shows up in the backend. I have even tried writing a public controller for the module and tried adding a route file but I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you posted:

shinokada (the developer)
May 10, 2011 at 10:40 am
The plug-in is only for admin area at the moment. You are welcome to extend it for the front-end.

Looks like the developer did not create any front end view. Looks like you might have to make that yourself =/